# Generic React Navite Application crashes instantly on testflight

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have an application that I have been working on that crashes when loaded into Testflight. I deicided to create a generic expo react native application to see what is causing the crash from the ground up.

I created a default react application and it loaded into test flight property after submitting to the apple developer console.

I then went ahead and just added a simple stack navigation and 1 home screen to see if that would run. My application crashed and all I did to the generic react native app was add a stack navigation and home screen. I have no clue how just adding those two things can possible cause a crash in testflight.

App.js:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

import HomeNavigation from './src/navigation/HomeNavigation';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <HomeNavigation />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});


export default App
```

HomeScreen.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        This is a blank app
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

HomeNavigation.js:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';

const StackNav = createStackNavigator();

const HomeNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <StackNav.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: true}}>
      <StackNav.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen}/>
    </StackNav.Navigator>
  )
}

export default HomeNavigation
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "rippeapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "patch-package": "^7.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

eas.json:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.14.0",
    "promptToConfigurePushNotifications": false
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "appleId": "...",
        "ascAppId": "...",
        "appleTeamId": "..."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "RippeApp",
    "slug": "RippeApp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.rippeinc.Rippe",
      "buildNumber": "2"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "..."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is actually so annoying for me because I have no idea why it is constantly crashing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have the dependencies

```
npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

[image: dependencies]

Here's a working example

https://snack.expo.dev/5YViI7pz7?platform=android

Further reading

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/#installing-dependencies-into-a-bare-react-native-project

Comment: It worked. This problem has been driving me crazy for 3 days. Thank you